# How can I run code if table name matches cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, foreach

I'm testing on an example sheet since the actual one has confidential data.

[image]

We have tables for each company, and there we list warnings for a manager or group of managers, then classify them as light or severe. I want to count them for each manager, considering that, if it's the same warning for multiple managers, we put them in the same cell.

```vb
Sub TesteA3()
'code 1:Set ID number for each company (company names can change so I needed a fixed ID)
Dim rcell As Range
Dim rrng As Range
Set rrng = Range("A2:A800")
'Since I'm using a sum to diffentiate the ID, I make sure to clear the range before any
Range("C2:E800").ClearContents
For Each rcell In rrng
    If rcell.Value = rcell.Offset(-1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(rcell) = False Then
        rcell.Offset(0, 5).Value = rcell.Offset(-1, 5).Value
    ElseIf rcell.Value <> rcell.Offset(-1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(rcell) = False Then
        rcell.Offset(0, 5).Value = rcell.Offset(-1, 5).Value + 1
    Else: If IsEmpty(rcell.Value) = True Then GoTo proximo
    End If
proximo:
Next rcell
'code 3:Sets an actual ID for each company. Since I'll use these ID's on the table later, I need them to not be plain numbers
Dim ncell As Range
Dim rrng2 As Range
Set rrng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F800")
For Each ncell In rrng2
    If IsEmpty(ncell) = False Then
        ncell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Company" & ncell.Value
        ncell.Clear
    Else
        GoTo proximo4
    End If
proximo4:
Next ncell
'code 3: Checks the erros and counts them
Dim rcell3 As Range
Dim rcell2 As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("B2:B12")
Set rng2 = Range("I3:I12")
For Each rcell3 In rng1
    For Each rcell2 In rng2
        If InStr(1, rcell2.Value, rcell3.Value) > 0 And rcell2.Offset(0, -2).Value = "X" Then
            rcell3.Offset(0, 1).Value = rcell3.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
        ElseIf InStr(1, rcell2.Value, rcell3.Value) > 0 And rcell2.Offset(0, -1).Value = "X" Then
            rcell3.Offset(0, 2).Value = rcell3.Offset(0, 2).Value + 1
        End If
    Next rcell2
Next rcell3
End Sub
```

The main issue is that sometimes the managers name are the same, and since I run the for each in the H:H range and not for each table, it would be counted twice for each company I have to run code 2 for each specific table if the name of the table matches the company's ID. I've already named the tables with their respective ID (Company1, Company2, respectively in the example sheet, so that's not an issue.

I'm trying something along the lines of

```vb
Dim co as ListObject
For each co In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
If ListObject.name = Range(rcell3).Offset(3,0).Value Then
''Run the code 2
```

I'm having a hard time doing `If`s and `For Each`s with tables.

Comment: Try `If co.name = ...`

Comment: I have been trying _If_ co.name = cell.Value (with cell set as range) _then_ but it does nothing. I'm not sure if they are different variables I'm trying to match, as I'm not sure what variable is ListObject.name considered.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `.Offset(3,0)` and not `.Offset(0,3)` ? You can add an ELSE block with `debug.print co.name, the value you are comparing it with`

Answer (score 0):

Process each company table separately by looping through all the tables looking for a table name that is `LIKE "Company*"`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TesteA3()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim sCo As String, sLastCo As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' or whatever
    
    ' add CompanyID to column E
    With ws
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       .Range("C2:E" & lastrow).Clear
       n = 0
       For r = 2 To lastrow
            sCo = Trim(.Cells(r, "A"))
            If Len(sCo) > 0 Then ' skip blank rows
                If sCo <> sLastCo Then
                    n = n + 1
                End If
                sLastCo = sCo
                .Cells(r, "E") = "Company" & n
            End If
       Next
    End With
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject, tblrow As Range, ID As String
    Dim colSevere As Long, colLight As Long, colMgr As Long
    Dim sSevere As String, sLight As String, sMgr As String
    
    ' process each company table
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        ID = tbl.Name
        If ID Like "Company*" Then
            
            colSevere = tbl.ListColumns("Severe").Index
            colLight = tbl.ListColumns("Light").Index
            colMgr = tbl.ListColumns("Manager").Index
            
            ' scan table rows
            For Each tblrow In tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows
                sSevere = UCase(tblrow.Cells(, colSevere))
                sLight = UCase(tblrow.Cells(, colLight))
                
                If sSevere = "X" Or sLight = "X" Then
                    sMgr = tblrow.Cells(, colMgr)
                    
                    ' scan company/manager table
                    For r = 2 To lastrow
                         ' match company ID and manager
                         If ws.Cells(r, "E") = ID _
                            And InStr(sMgr, ws.Cells(r, "B")) > 0 Then
                                ' increase counts
                                If sSevere = "X" Then
                                    ws.Cells(r, "C") = ws.Cells(r, "C") + 1
                                End If
                                If sLight = "X" Then
                                    ws.Cells(r, "D") = ws.Cells(r, "D") + 1
                                End If
                         End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
       End If
    Next
    
     MsgBox "Done", vbInformation

End Sub
```